# Bigquery: does Google bill for canceled query?

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery console, after running a query for 2 minutes I hit "stop" (before it ended).

Is google billing me for this?

Comment: Canceled query should not be billed! unless it somehow anyway was completed - let's say because you hit "Cancel" too late ... and query has actually completed already

Answer (score 0):

It depends on query processing stage. The query may still be billed, even if cancelled:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/cancel

Requests that a job be cancelled. ... **Cancelled jobs may still incur costs.**

Comment: I am using Bigquery console, and it seems that queries there "live in different scope" of the job scope, that means that I can't see my queries under "job history" (left menu), only under "query history". 
There I can find my canceled query and it says something like: "Bytes processed 29.08 MB, Bytes billed 30 MB" (The actual query was way bigger, like 500mb and I canceled it at least one minute before it was suppose to end).